# how to solve an listining error in javascript & json

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

```
//importing pckg

const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const path = require('path');

//inisialisation express.js
const app = express();

//routes

//home route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
})

app.listen(5500, () => {
  console.log('listning on port 5500................');
})
```

I have problem  in my server.js. I am working on ecommerce website database with firebase & json & javascript and i have a error. It doesn't do listen at all and this the result.

Comment: I noticed you tagged javascript and not node. Are you running this through a server? Because this code will not work in client side javascript.

Comment: "i have a error" — What error?

Comment: "it doesn't do listen at all" — Do you mean that the console log statement on the penultimate line doesn't run?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `app.get("/")`, you are sending HTML content in browser, make sure the path of `public/index.html` available.

To test the server, just add below code & check it.

```
res.send(" hello there");
```

in `app.get("/")`